# Why is pattern matching preferred in function definitions?

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching, signature

I am reading the "learnyouahaskell" tutorial from [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). There it reads:

> Pattern matching can also be used on tuples. What if we wanted to make
>   a function that takes two vectors in a 2D space (that are in the form
>   of pairs) and adds them together? To add together two vectors, we add
>   their `x` components separately and then their `y` components
>   separately. Here's how we would have done it if we didn't know about
>   pattern matching:
>
> ```
> addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)  
> addVectors a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
> ```
>
> Well, that works, but there's a better way to do it. Let's modify the
>   function so that it uses pattern matching.
>
> ```
> addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)  
> addVectors (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
> ```
>
> There we go! Much better. Note that this is already a catch-all
>   pattern. The type of `addVectors` (in both cases) is `addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) - > (a, a)`, so we are guaranteed to get
>   two pairs as parameters.

My question is: Why is the pattern matching preferred the preferred way, if both definitions result in the same signature?

Comment: well compare them - what is easier to read? Isn't it so much nicer and closer to the actual definition? You don't have to parse/understand `fst` and `snd` either to understand the function...

Comment: and **no offense meant** but this is just a question asking for opinions - there will never be **the** answer (or any right one for that matter) - this is why I vote to close it

Comment: @Carsten Hm you might have a point about readability. I read it and was thinking: _but that's the same in more code_. Now that you mention one doesn't have to know `fst` and `snd` I can see that there might be a readability advantage.

Comment: The pattern-matching version looks yet better if you make some subtle layout modifications, like `addVectors (x₁,y₁) (x₂,y₂) = (x₁+x₂, y₁+y₂)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in this case the pattern matching expresses more directly what you mean.

In the function application case, one needs to know what `fst` and `snd` do, and from it deduce that `a` and `b` are tuples whose elements get added.

```
addVectors a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
```

The fact that we have `snd` and `fst` functions to decompose tuples is distracting here.

In the pattern matching case it is immediately clear what the input is (a tuple whose elements we call `x1` and `y1` and a tuple... etc) and how it is deconstructed. And it is also immediately clear what is happening, how their elements are added.

```
addVectors (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

This is almost like the mathematical definition:

> (*x<sub>1</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>*) + (*x<sub>2</sub>*, *y<sub>2</sub>*) := (*x<sub>1</sub>* + *x<sub>2</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>* + *y<sub>2</sub>*)

Straight to the point, no distractions :-)

You could literally write this in Haskell:

```
(x₁, y₁) `addVector` (x₂, y₂) = (x₁ + x₂, y₁ + y₂)
```

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, one needs to construct and destruct values.

Values are constructed by taking a data constructor which is a (possibly null-ary) function, and applying the required arguments. So far, so good.

Random example (abusing `GADTSyntax`)

```
data T where
  A :: Int -> T
  B :: T
  C :: String -> Bool -> T
```

Destruction is more complex, since one needs to take a value of type `T` and obtain information about 1) which constructor was used to craft such value, and 2) what are the arguments to said constructor.

Part 1) could be done through a function:

```
whichConsT :: T -> Int -- returns 0,1,2 for A,B,C
```

Part 2) is more tricky. A possible option is to use projections

```
projA :: T -> Int
-- projB not needed
projC1 :: T -> String
projC2 :: T -> Bool
```

so that e.g. they satisfy

```
projA (A n) = n
projC1 (C x y) = x
projC2 (C x y) = y
```

But wait! The types of the projections are of the form `T -> ...`, which promises that such functions work on all values of type `T`. So we can have

```
projA B = ??
projA (C x y) = ??
projC1 (A n) = ??
```

How to implement the above? There's no way to produce sensible results, so the best option is to trigger a runtime error.

```
projA B = error "not an A!"
projA (C x y) = error "not an A!"
projC1 (A n) = error "not a C!"
```

However, *this puts a burden on the programmer*! Now it is the programmer's responsibility to check that values which are passed to the projections have the right constructor. This can be done using `whichConsT`. Many imperative programmers are used to this kind of interface (test & access, e.g. Java's `hasNext(), next()` in iterators), but this is because most imperative languages have no really better option.

FP languages (and, nowadays, some imperative languages as well) also allow pattern matching. Using it has the following advantages over projections:

- no need to split the information: we get 1) and 2) at the same time
- no way to crash the program: we never use partial projection functions which can crash
- no burden on the programmer: corollary of the above
- if the exhaustiveness-checker is on, we are sure to handle all the possible cases

Now, on types having exactly *one* constructor (tuples, `()`, `newtype`s), one can define total projections, which are perfectly fine (e.g. `fst,snd`). Still, many prefer to stick with pattern matching, which can also handle the general case as well.

Answer (score 2):

As **Carsten** mentioned in comments, this is an opinion-based question, but let me elaborate anyway.

Using pattern matching against 2-tuples isn't that much of an advantage, but let's consider some bigger data structure, for example 4-tuples.

```
addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a, a, a) -> (a, a, a, a) -> (a, a, a, a)  
addVectors a b = -- some code that adds vectors

addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a, a, a) -> (a, a, a, a) -> (a, a, a, a)  
addVectors (w1, x1, y1, z1) (w2, x2, y2, z2) = (w1 + w2, x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2)
```

Without pattern matching you'd have to write functions that extract the first, second, third and fourth element from a 4-tuple an use it inside `addVectors`. With pattern matching, writing the implementation of `addVectors` is very easy.

I believe using such an example in the book could get the message across more effectively.

Comment: [`addVectors a b = (a^._1 + b^._1, a^._2 + b^._2, a^._3 + b^._3, a^._4 + b^._4)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html). And, I don't think it would be that clever to use four-tuples as an example, since basically nobody uses tuples larger than three. What brings the message across properly is pattern like those on list cons cells.